# Infinite loop/recursion when implement quicksort in java

Tags: java, loops, recursion, quicksort

I'm attempting to implement quicksort in java in order to count the number of comparisons made, but I'm running into an infinite loop/recursive call situation, and I can't quite figure out where it's coming from.

Through debugging I've determined that the inner for loop runs however many times, and everything is only entered into "less" sublist, and then a recursive call is made to quicksort(less)

```
    private ArrayList<Comparable> quickSort(ArrayList<Comparable> qList) {
            ArrayList<Comparable> less = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
            ArrayList<Comparable> greater = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
            if (qList.size() <= 1)
                return qList;
            Comparable pivot = qList.get(qList.size() / 2);
            for (int i = 0; i < qList.size(); i++) {
                if ((qList.get(i).compareTo(pivot)) <= 0) {
                    comps++;
                    less.add(qList.get(i));
                } else {
                    comps++;
                    greater.add(qList.get(i));
                }
            }

            ArrayList<Comparable> toReturn = new ArrayList<Comparable>(
                    quickSort(less));
            toReturn.add(pivot);
            toReturn.addAll(quickSort(greater));
            return toReturn;

        }
```

If I just run the code with a list of size 20, I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
    at file.quickSort(CMSC351P1.thisClass:40)
    at file.quickSort(CMSC351P1.thisClass:48)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you add the pivot element itself to the 'less' list so the base case never terminates.

**Example:
You sort the list [0, 0] with your algorithm. The pivot element is ... 0. The 'less' list that your algorithm produces is again [0, 0], and you enter in infinite loop.**

Comment: The actual problem in my opinion is that the pivot is NOT removed from the list when splitting to higher and lower lists; you're adding an element with every iteration...

Comment: Yes, well, only after recursion though.

Comment: ah that's right. I should have used remove rather than get. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't exclude the pivot from the less/greater sublists -- in fact, you explicitly include it in the sublist set. I suspect this means you'll get stuck with lists of two being infinitely sorted in many cases. You'll need to exclude the pivot from the less sublist.

Answer (score 0):

You don't ensure that you partition the list so that the greater list is decreased in size by 1 or more or the less list is decreased in size by 1 or more.

At some point, if the pivot is the largest element in the list, then everything will go to the "less" list.

When you call it, the same thing will happen again.